# Why don't I get information from `apropos pthread` in Terminal on OS X?

Tags: macos, terminal, c

When I run `apropos pthread` in Terminal on OS X, I get `pthread: nothing appropriate`. However, when I run the same command on a Linux machine, I get over a hundred APIs for reference in man-pages. I know the APIs are on my Mac, because when I run `man 3 pthread_create`, it takes me to the appropriate man-page.

Why don't I get suggestions from apropos on OS X? How can I get the same useful information from apropos on pthreads as I do on a Linux machine?

NOTE: I ran `sudo /usr/libexec/makewhatis` to see if updating the apropos database would help, but it didn't.

Comment: I'm running 10.14 and it works for me.  Are you missing Xcode command line utils ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hogstrom figured it out for me. I didn't have Xcode command line utils installed. I'm not totally sure whether it was command line utils or `xcode-select --install` that did it. Either way, it works now...